# do off screen html elements still get rendered by the browser

Tags: html, browser, rendering

I have my body tag fill the browser window and it has a collection of div elements I'll refer to as screens. Only one screen is displayed at a time, filling the body tag, and the other screens sit off the edge of the browser view port. I want to know whether I should set them to `display:none;` to save the browser doing anywork rendering them. Or does the browser already know they are off screen and leave them alone until they come back on?

Comment: I say go with `display: none`, browsers will render all elements

Comment: Even if you set the element to `display:none`. browser knows that there is an element offscreen and still renders it. There is no way if can save the browser doing any work if the element is included in your html file.

Comment: They'd have to be rendered before the browser could know they're off screen. :x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[link](http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm#The_render_tree_relation_to_the_DOM_tree) shows that `display:none` elements do not get inserted to the render tree and so performance gains may be achieved by setting off screen elements to `display:none`.